# Sharepoint 2016 REST API Authentication mechanism

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, authentication

We have a sharepoint 2016 instance and a C# application connects to it. we need to read documents and upload documents from C# application to Sharepoint using REST Api.

Would like to see the industry standard approach on the REST API Authentication mechanism to be followed for this kind of application.

Please note our instanse is not Office 365 and it is Sharepoint 2016. Also if possible pointers to various authentication mechanism for SP 2016 REST Api will also be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.